# Is there another way to pass/store the props that doesn't feel like a bodge?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I have to pass/store data in my ReactTS App. Everything works, but it doesnt feel right.
I have 4 Components and they pass `meal` around.

`meal` comes from another component to `MealDetails` (the component needs it to work). It passes `meal` to `AddFood` (bec it has to jump back to `MealDetails` at one point - so it needs `meal`).
An important function is in `BarcodeScannerPluginReworks` so this needs `meal` aswell through `BarcodeScannerRework`, because this one jumps back to `AddFood`.

So im sending `meal` in a circle. Is there a way to save it in `MealDetails` and only pass a function to `AddFood` to change some values in `meal` instead of sending it full circle.

MealDetails.tsx

```
const MealDetails = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { meal } = location.state || {};
  

  return (
    <div className="MealDetails">
      <Link className="Link" to={`/AddFood/${meal.id}`} state={{ meal: meal }}>
        <div className="MealDetailsAddFoodButton">
          <img className="SVG" src={SVG} alt="+21" />
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
```

AddFood.tsx

```
const AddFood = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const mealId = useParams();

  const { meal } = location.state || {};

  return (
    <div className="AddFood">
      <header className="AddFoodHeader">
        <div className="BackArrow-Meal">
          <ArrowBackIcon
            onClick={() => {
              navigate(`/MealDetails/${mealId.id}`, { state: { meal : meal } });
            }}
            sx={{ fontSize: 35 }}
          ></ArrowBackIcon>
        </div>
        <div className="AddFoodSearchBar">
          <Link className="Link" to={`/BarcodeScanner/`} state={{ meal : meal }} >
            <CropFreeIcon className="QRIcon"sx={{ fontSize: 30 }}></CropFreeIcon>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};
```

BarcodeScannerRework.jsx

```
const BarcodeScannerRework = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();

    const { meal } = location.state;

  return (
    <div className="BarcodeScannerRework">
      <div className="BarcodeScannerReworkPlugin">
        <BarcodeScannerPluginRework meal={meal}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

BarcodeScannerPluginRework.jsx

```
const BarcodeScannerPluginRework = ({meal}) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  let html5QrCode;
  useEffect(() => { //I've shortened this part a lot - it navigates when there is a successful response
          navigate(`/AddFood/${meal.id}`, { state: { eanCodeFromCamera : decodedText , meal : meal} 
  });

  return <div id={qrcodeId}></div>;
};
```

Comment: You could use Redux or a Context.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on a state from the location. Going directly to the url will cause the state to be empty

Comment: @Konrad yeah I know, but I thought its not that big of a deal if its only for friends. What would you do?

Comment: @Arkellys Yeah I heard of that, do you maybe have an example of the Context way?

Comment: @Cinc-B I will try to write something quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different solutions possible when you have many components that need to share a state.

#### 1. Using props and a common parent

The most common method is set the state on a common parent and then pass it as a prop. But it's not always possible if your components are all over the place or if you have a lot of nested components.

#### 2. Redux

[Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) is an external library which give you the possibility to have a global state (a store) for your app. It lets your components read data from the store, and dispatch actions to the store to update the state.

#### 3. Context

React's [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) is a built-in solution which also allow you to share data for a tree of components. Given your question, it might be the best solution for you. Here is a basic example on how to implement it:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

const MealContext = createContext();

const MealProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [meal, setMeal] = useState(/* Initial meal value */);

  const addFood = (food) => {
    // Do something with meal...
  };

  return (
    <MealContext.Provider
      value={{
        addFood,
        meal
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MealContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useMeal = () => useContext(MealContext); // Custom hook to use the context

export { MealProvider, useMeal };
```

You can then set the provider where you need to manage `meal`:

```
<MealProvider>
  <MealDetails />
  <AddFood />
</MealProvider>
```

And on your component:

```
const AddFood = () => {
  const { meal, addFood } = useMeal();

  return (/* ... */);
}
```

Please read the documentation carefully to understand better how to use the Context API. I also recommend [this article](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#context-and-rendering-behavior), which explain how the rendering behavior of Context works.

Answer (score 0):

I build a `globalstate` library [react-global-state-management](https://github.com/AlenToma/react-global-state-management) It is much easier to work with than context or redux

```js
import GlobalState from 'react-global-state-management';
const data = GlobalState({
  meal:...,
  addFood:()=> {}
  ...
});

/ component 1
()=> {
  data.meal =// something
  
  return ()
  

}

/// component 2

()=> {
    // bind a hook so when meal changes the component gets updated
    data.hook(x=> [x.meal])
    
    data.subscripe((item, prop)=> {
        /// meal has changed
        //  use this togather with or without hook
    }, x=> [x.meal])
    data.addFood(...)
    
    return //something
    
    
}
```